# Which one is a better method to use: variable.split("_"); or variable.split(/_/);?

Tags: javascript

which one is better between quotes and slash, not just in `split` method, but in other methods to search a string within a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very good reason to prefer a string wherever possible, which is that `split()` is broken in IE with regular expressions. See JavaScript regex guru Steven Levithan's blog post about this: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

So, the following will work in all browsers:

```
"1__2".split("_"); // returns ["1", "", "2"]
```

... while the following returns inconsistent results:

```
"1__2".split(/_/); // ["1", "2"] in IE, ["1", "", "2"] in others
```

Answer (score 5):

```
variable.split("_");
```

would be best for a single char search like that because it would avoid creating a RegEx.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is splitting on a `String`, the second one is splitting on a `RegExp`.

In this case, they are [functionality equivalent](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/chgB7/). I would use the `String`, however, as the `RegExp` is unnecessary.

I would use a `String` where I could, and a `RegExp` where the situation calls for it.

Answer (score 3):

probably gonna have to benchmark it, but I would assume the string methods are faster...they usually are.

Answer (score 2):

## [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/split-vs-split)

As you can see the `split(' ')` is faster